# How to add custom javascript to the kyestonejs admin ui

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

How I can add some custom javascript to the keystone admin?

Now there is an option called "adminui custom styles" for loading a custom css, there is something similar for javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It currently isn't possible without directly modifying the Keystone admin panel code (in its `node_modules` folder).

Public assets (CSS/JS) for the admin UI are located in [`admin/public`](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/admin/public). The HTML file that you can use to implement your own JavaScript files is located in [`admin/server/templates/index.html`](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/admin/server/templates/index.html). From there, you can import whatever custom JavaScript or CSS that you need to.

Comment: Do you now an easy way to do this?

Comment: I just added some more info to my original answer to show you where to go to add custom JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, but I gitignore node_modules. I can't track my changes in that file.

Comment: Keystone has no native way of implementing custom JS. The only way you could do it is to fork Keystone on NPM and make your changes, but that might be a lot. [Admin extensibility is on the developers' roadmap, though,](https://keystonejs.canny.io/feature-requests/p/admin-interface-extensibility) so there is hope.